# How do I switch back to Ati after changing to Intel on Linux Switchable?

Tags: debian, graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I have a laptop with Ati/Intel combo. I am using Amd driver on Debian Jessie 64. I was able to use the Ati driver with it for a while. Then I decided to switch back to Intel card using the Ati/Amd control panel for battery purposes. However now I have a dilemma. Fglrxinfo is giving me seg fault and amdccle s giving me

```
amdcccle 

(process:12129): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed
Segmentation fault
```

I assume that now it thinks that this pc has no Amd card anymore.

```
aticonfig --px-dgpu
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

How do I get back to Ati driver? I am unable to find a way. Ideally I would like to be able to just switch back and forth without hasssle. This is just sad.

```
3.12-1-amd64

lspci |grep -i vga (as you see the ati is not even listed here, but it is in the laptop)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

some dmesg

```
 5.014790] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    5.024249] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    5.024252] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[    5.024572] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    5.025182] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    5.025264] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:27/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input9
[    5.025484] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    5.025496] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    5.025505] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    5.025516] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    5.025526] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    5.025535] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    5.025545] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    5.026199] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    5.026263] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:09/input/input10
[    5.026386] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    5.026648] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 52 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.039329] hda_codec: ALC275: SKU not ready 0x411111f0
[    5.041625] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/input/input11
[    5.047535] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[    5.047618] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    5.047684] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[    5.805203] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[    5.980909] EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    6.141661] EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    6.375841] loop: module loaded
[    6.402569] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[    6.829082] tusbd: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

134.039852] fglrx_pci 0000:01:00.0: irq 53 for MSI/MSI-X
[  134.040322] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 5920
[  134.040432] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 5921
[  134.040556] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 5922
[  134.040661] <6>[fglrx] IRQ 53 Enabled
[  134.087922] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[  134.087925] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f878000, size:4000 
[  134.087926] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f87c000, size:484000 
[  134.087927] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:1fff4000, size:c000 
[  304.908413] <6>[fglrx] IRQ 53 Disabled
[  305.012089] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=none,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
[  305.016699] <6>[fglrx] module unloaded - fglrx 13.25.5 [Dec  6 2013]
[  305.018252] vgaarb: invalid PCI address 0:1:0
[  324.933530] amdcccle[8124]: segfault at c ip 00007f43e380f0a0 sp 00007fff598a6908 error 4 in libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0[7f43e3804000+15000]
[  359.901130] fgl_glxgears[8364]: segfault at c ip 00007f33880560a0 sp 00007fffc61a2fa8 error 4 in libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0[7f338804b000+15000]
[  370.023260] fglrxinfo[8431]: segfault at c ip 00007fc671cfa0a0 sp 00007fff936d8b78 error 4 in libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0[7fc671cef000+15000]
[  384.532181] amdcccle[8531]: segfault at c ip 00007fbeaf9bd0a0 sp 00007fffab4b30e8 error 4 in libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0[7fbeaf9b2000+15000]
```

Comment: Most people that switch from ATI don't watch to switch back.

Comment: thanks but that is not very useful to my situation